# Is import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable'; acceptable?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I can see in the documentation that the syntax is `import { Observable } from 'rxjs';` but is `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable` any better?

Comment: Any better how? It is never recommended to use resources not exposed through public APIs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If we look at the [source code](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/index.ts) of rxjs, the `Observable` exported under `'rxjs'` is:

```
export { Observable } from './internal/Observable';
```

In other words, it's the exact same object as the one in `'rxjs/internal/Observable'`.

You should import from the public API, not internal paths. Library developers will try to minimize changes in the public API between different versions of the library. If you use the public API, it is more likely you can upgrade the library without changing your code.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not better. Things may change internally that may not be reflected in the public API.

As such, your import may break in a future release (that is not marked as having breaking changes).

Comment: I think that would be a mistake by the maintainer of the library. As for RxJS, breaking changes come with a major release: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md When using internal import paths, your code could be broken by a simple refactoring that has no effect on the public API.

Answer (score 0):

For my experience you should use public API path.

I have encounter a problem when using internal path when running `ng build --prod` the build will throw error and when you use public API path you can easily upgrade in the future without modify a lot of your code